# Smoothing Bezier Curves in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, bezier-curves

I have a strange curvature showing when I generate a curve with animation nodes. I can "fix" the appearance by choosing "Cyclic" but I need a start and an end in order to animate.

The first screenshot below shows the curve I am getting and the second, the curve I would like but not cyclical.

The curve starts and stops on the large sphere.

[image: bad curve]

[image: nice curve]

Here is a screenshot showing the results with a center point added.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the handles of the spline points to be along the normals of the surface points as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thank you Omar! I replicated your code successfully. However I need a center point to control the height of the arc. When I add a center point it also gets the handle information. Is there a way to set handles for individual points?

Comment: @fvlasie Sure, just create a list with the new handles. What are you having trouble with? Also, I think scaling the normals before adding should be sufficient to control the height.

Comment: I am not sure what value to use for the middle point handles. It always seems too sharp.

Comment: @fvlasie Settings the handles manually is not very easy. Not sure how we should go about doing that. Let me think about it.